# js math function returns nan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to write a couple of simple js functions and the first one (and the most simple one) doesn't seem to work. this one is my html page, I have no css.
FunctionLib.js is my file and other script imports jquery(it worked perfectly in my other project)
I just need to show the answer of the function squareSum after the button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- МЕТА-ІНФОРМАЦІЯ -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/FunctionLib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="square-sum">
    <form name="mathematics">
        Enter х: <input type="number" id="x-square"> <br>
        Enter y: <input type="number" id="y-square"> <br>
        <button onclick="squareSumContainer()">OK</button>
    </form>
    <p>x^2+y^2 = <span id="square-answer"></span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my js file:

```
function squareSum(a, b) {
    return a * a + b * b;
}

function squareSumContainer() {
    var x = parseInt($('#x-square').html(), 10);
    var y = parseInt($('#y-square').html(), 10);
    $("#square-answer").html(squareSum(x, y));
    //document.getElementById("square-answer").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);
    var answer = squareSum(x, y);
    //alert(answer);
}
```

And when I press the button nothing happened. I tried using alert to show the answer and it appeared to be NaN.
I am extremely new to js so I don't know what to do at all.

Comment: `input`'s don't have `html()` they have `val()`

Comment: `$('#x-square').html()` -> `$('#x-square').val()`

Comment: @Bravo thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @Bravo and @freedomn-m said, the problem was in the part where I tried to use .html() on input instead of .val()